# E4X to JSON conversion fails for duplicate xml elements

Tags: mirth

Kindly see below code I am using to convert Mirth xml to JSON.

```
function E4XtoJSON(xml, ignored) {
  var r, children = xml.*, attributes = xml.@*, length = children.length();
  if(length == 0) {
    r = xml.toString();
  } else if(length == 1) {
    var text = xml.text().toString();
    if(text) {
      r = text;
    }
  }
  if(r == undefined) { 
    r = {};
    for each (var child in children) {
     var name = child.localName();
     var json = E4XtoJSON(child, ignored);
     var value = r[name];
     if(value) {
       if(value.length) {
         value.push(json);
       } else {
         r[name] = [value, json]
       }
     } else {
       r[name] = json;
     }
    }
  }
  if(attributes.length()) {
    var a = {}, c = 0;
    for each (var attribute in attributes) {
      var name = attribute.localName();
      if(ignored && ignored.indexOf(name) == -1) {
        a["_" + name] = attribute.toString();
        c ++;
      }
    }
    if(c) {
      if(r) a._ = r;
      return a;
    }
  }

  return r;
}
```

---

My concern is

```
<AdditionalMessageInformationCount AdditionalMessageInformationCount="02"><AdditionalMessageInformationQualifier>01</AdditionalMessageInformationQualifier><AdditionalMessageInformation>MEMBER MUST USE MAIL ORDER.</AdditionalMessageInformation><AdditionalMessageInformationQualifier>02</AdditionalMessageInformationQualifier><AdditionalMessageInformation>PLAN LIMITATIONS EXCEEDED</AdditionalMessageInformation></AdditionalMessageInformationCount>
```

Here AdditionalMessageInformation elemt is used two times so function fails to create JSON.
Kindly help if anyone have converted XML in json usingg javascript code not any API

Answer (score 0):

We've had success with this version:

```
function E4XtoJSON(xml, ignored){
var r, children = xml.*,
    attributes = xml.@ * ,
    length = children.length();
if (length == 0)
{
    r = xml.toString();
}
else if (length == 1)
{
    var text = xml.text().toString();
    if (text)
    {
        r = text;
    }
}
if (r == undefined)
{
    r = {};
    for each(var child in children)
    {
        var name = child.localName();
        var json = E4XtoJSON(child, ignored);
        var value = r[name];
        if (value)
        {
            if (value instanceof Array)
            {
                value.push(json);
            }
            else
            {
                r[name] = [value, json]
            }
        }
        else
        {
            r[name] = json;
        }
    }
}
if (attributes.length())
{
    var a = {},
        c = 0;
    for each(var attribute in attributes)
    {
        var name = attribute.localName();
        if (ignored && ignored.indexOf(name) == -1)
        {
            a["_" + name] = attribute.toString();
            c++;
        }
    }
    if (c)
    {
        if (r) a._ = r;
        return a;
    }
}
return r;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

With the release of Mirth Connect version 3.3.0, you can use Mirth Connect to set your channel's interior data type to JSON. This will all be done for you.

Comment: It won't do this for you. That is only used when the inbound data is already JSON. It won't convert from xml to json for you.